# Laravel Eloquent hasMany Specific Relationship Row Return

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables with following sample data

**Courses**

| id | cl1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |

**Offers**

| id | course_id | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020 |
| 3 | 2 | 2019 |

in the respective model one to many relationship is defined normally(works fine)

I want to select course with offers of a certain year value only with the selected relationship only.

when i try the following code it gives me correct course table row but returns both id 1 and 2 of the offers table in the relationship.

```
Course::with(['offer'])
            ->whereHas('offer', function ($q) {
                $q->where('year',2020);
            })                
            ->get();
```

how can i get only the selected relationship(for this example id 2 only).

fyi: Due to some other need i can not use **Offer::with(['course'])**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use same logic for eager loading

```
Course::with(['offer' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('year', 2020);
}])->whereHas('offer', function ($query) {
    $query->where('year', 2020);
})->get();
```

It could be simplified by saving a closure to the variable

```
Course::with(['offer' => $closure = function ($query) {
    $query->where('year', 2020);
}])->whereHas('offer', $closure)->get();
```